# Extract geometry from citygml data using citygml4j

Tags: java, citygml

I have a citygml file with some buildings. And I am trying to extract the geometry of the polygon in that building using the citygml4j library. I have looked at the FeatureWalker class but I am unable to get the geometry of the polygon.

Can anyone let me know how this can be done?

```
    CityGMLContext ctx = new CityGMLContext();
    CityGMLBuilder builder = ctx.createCityGMLBuilder();

    CityGMLInputFactory in = builder.createCityGMLInputFactory();
    CityGMLReader reader = in.createCityGMLReader(new File("/home/vishal/NWW/sampleData/LOD2_Building_v100.gml"));

    while(reader.hasNext())
    {
        CityGML citygml = reader.nextFeature();
        System.out.println("Found class:" + citygml.getCityGMLClass() + "\nVersion"+citygml.getCityGMLModule().getVersion());

        //Counting the no of buildings
        CityModel citymodel = new CityModel();
        if(citygml.getCityGMLClass() == CityGMLClass.CITY_MODEL)
        {
            citymodel = (CityModel)citygml;
            // Counting the no of buildings
            int count=0;
            for(CityObjectMember cityObjectMember : citymodel.getCityObjectMember())
            {
                AbstractCityObject cityobject = cityObjectMember.getCityObject();
                if(cityobject.getCityGMLClass() == CityGMLClass.BUILDING)
                {
                    ++count;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Building count"+count);
        }

        FeatureWalker walker = new FeatureWalker(){
            public void visit(Building building){
                System.out.println(building.getId());
                //MultiSurface multisurface = boundrysurface.getLod2MultiSurface().getMultiSurface();
                //System.out.println(multisurface.getSurfaceMember().get(0));
                List<BoundarySurfaceProperty> list = building.getBoundedBySurface();
                System.out.println(list);
                System.out.println(list.get(0).getBoundarySurface());
                //HOW TO GET THE POLYGON AND ITS COORDINATES??
            }
        };
        citymodel.accept(walker);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can collect all polygons of a city object by using a GMLWalker

```
GMLWalker gmlWalker= new GMLWalker() {
      public void visit(Polygon polygon) {

        if (polygon.isSetExterior()) {
            AbstractRing exteriorAbstractRing = polygon.getExterior().getRing();
            ...
        }
      }
    };

cityObject.accept(gmlWalker);
```

Have a look at the [3D City Database repo](https://github.com/3dcitydb/importer-exporter). The Importer/Exporter tool takes extensive use of citygml4j.