# Extract polygon-coordinates from citygml data using citygml4j

Tags: polygon, coordinates, citygml

My question is closely related to [Extract geometry from citygml data using citygml4j](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/143598)

I have a citygml file with buildings and I need to extract the coordinates of each roof surface. I use the open source library citygml4j. My code is almost the same as in the link, but I am stuck at the line:

```
AbstractRing exteriorAbstractRing = polygon.getExterior().getRing();
```

How do you extract the coordinates of the polygon-geometry from here?

---

Found the solution with help from @JulianRosse. There are some solution if is a LinearRing, e.g.:

```
((LinearRing)polygon.getExterior().getRing()).toList3d()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the LinearRing class and casting to that. Calling .toList3d() on a LinearRing will return a List of the coordinates. I would use an IDE with code-completion to help with navigating the citygml4j model.